# Strategy for Continuous Integration on Laravel

Tags: php, git, laravel-5, continuous-deployment

Consider the following scenario:

A `code-release.sh` script accepts a ready-to-go branch name that gets pushed to [Bit Bucket](http://bitbucket.org)'s git repository. A web hook triggers [Code Ship](http://codeship.com) so all tests gets executed as a CI strategy where, on success, a [php script](https://gist.github.com/oodavid/1809044#file-deploy-php) is requested on my application's domain.

Now, my goal is that this script can get the release ready to be used, so I have to

1. git pull [master]
2. composer update
3. php artisan migrate

At this point my instincts SCREAMS not to run an automatic `php artisan migrate` because it will stink at some point. But that would mean the need for human-intervention whenever there's a migration to be executed and possibly code breakage after the continuous-integration sets off the deployment and before someone runs the migration manually.

What I could come up with was a step to call a `database-backup.sh` right before the migration gets executed.

Anyway, I'm sure there's someone out there using Laravel and CI/CD and I'd like to know how could this situation be addressed.

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but you should be doing composer install, if you use update packages can change and you could end up with issues on production. Update yourself in dev, confirm everything is working, and then commit the lock file, and prod will get the same packages when running install.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to set up Continuous Integration for a JavaScript front-end and Laravel back-end.  I did this with Jenkins.

The build job for the Laravel followed [this](https://jenkins.io/solutions/php) recipe.

All php tools were installed on the build server and added to the PATH.

Worked as advertised.